# Impossible to save collection of strings to LiteDb

Tags: c#, nosql, litedb

I am trying to save collection of the strings to LiteDb

```
using (var db = new LiteDatabase(@"MyData.db"))
{
    var col = db.GetCollection<string>("Writers");
    col.Insert("Mark Twain");
    col.Insert("Jack London");
 }
```

It throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at LiteDB.BsonMapper.ToDocument[T](T entity) on Insert.

Code like this works:

```
public class Writer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

using (var db = new LiteDatabase(@"MyData.db"))
{
    var col = db.GetCollection<Writer>("Writers");
    col.Insert(new Writer { Name = "Mark Twain" });
    col.Insert(new Writer { Name = "Jack London" });
}
```

Why? What's wrong with the string?

Comment: It is not a duplication of "What is a NullReferenceException". Null reference is in LiteDb code.

Comment: @rene. No. There are no "Writers" collection in my Db. I tried with empty database. Result is the same.

Comment: @rene. It works with the Writer class. It does not work with the string.

Comment: Maybe it's because strings are immutable in C#. There are only 2 options: you can try look through the code of BsonMapper or ask LiteDb developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LiteDB is a "Document Store" database, so you can only store documents. You can't store inside a collection any primitive data type or array.

Document structure is required because each document must contains an unique `_id` value field. If you do not provide (like in your example), LiteDB will auto create this Id field using `ObjectId`.

If you want avoid create this class, you can use `BsonDocument` to be more simple to use.

```
using (var db = new LiteDatabase(@"MyData.db"))
{
    var col = db.GetCollection("Writers");
    col.Insert(new BsonDocument { ["Name"] = "Mark Twain" });
    col.Insert(new BsonDocument { ["Name"] = "Jack London" });
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. I think LiteDb should return more meaningful exception in this case ;(